# Drawing lines in Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, drawing, swift, uigraphicscontext

I'm drawing a horizontal line and a vertical line on a `UITableViewCell` using the following code and it works fine on iOS7. Its in Objective-C.

In the subclass of the,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *columns;

- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // In iOS7, you have to set the cell's background color to clear otherwise the drawing lines won't appear
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    // Drawing the vertical line
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.75);
    for (int i = 0; i < self.columns.count; i++) {
        CGFloat f = [((NSNumber*) [self.columns objectAtIndex:i]) floatValue];
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, f, 10);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, f, self.bounds.size.height - 10);
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx);

    // Drawing the horizontal line
    CGContextRef cntx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(cntx, 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < self.columns.count; i++) {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(cntx, 15, self.bounds.size.height / 2);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(cntx, 60, self.bounds.size.height / 2);
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(cntx);

    [super drawRect:rect];
}

- (void)addColumn:(CGFloat)position
{
    [self.columns addObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:position]];
}
```

And it looks like this,

[image]

I'm trying to implement the same in Swift. However those lines don't appear. Here is my code so far,

```
var columns: [CGFloat] = []

override func drawRect(rect: CGRect)  {

    // Drawing the vertical line
    let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(ctx, 0.75)
    for var i = 0; i < self.columns.count; i++ {
        let f = self.columns[i] as? float // Error - Use of module 'float' as a type
        CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, f, 10)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, f, self.bounds.size.height - 10)
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(ctx)

    // Drawing the horizontal line
    let cntx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(ctx, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 1.0)
    CGContextSetLineWidth(cntx, 1)
    for var i = 0; i < self.columns.count; i++ {
        CGContextMoveToPoint(cntx, 15, self.bounds.size.height / 2)
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(cntx, 60, self.bounds.size.height / 2)
    }
    CGContextStrokePath(cntx)

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()

    super.drawRect(rect)
}

func addColumn(position: CGFloat) {
    self.columns.append(NSNumber.numberWithFloat(position)) // Error - 'NSNumber' is not a subtype of 'Float'
}
```

Multiple errors come up in the first block of the code. The error message is **'AnyObject' is not convertible to 'CGFloat'**.
No errors in the second block but still the line doesn't appear.

Can someone please tell me what I'm missing here?

Thank you.

Comment: I suppose it's the line with let f = self.columns[i].
Try casting to float instead let f = self.columns[i] as? float. 
Didn't try that myself. I'm VERY new to Swift too.

Comment: @Akaino is most definitely right, the type of f is wrong. You should use [CGFloat] as the type for the self.columns array instead of NSArray

Comment: Hi, thank you both of the responses. I changed the type of the array like this `var columns: [CGFloat] = []` and changed the error throwing line to this `let f = self.columns[i] as? float` but I get a new error saying **Use of module 'float' as a type**. I also forgot to mention that there's a method that adds objects to the columns array. I tried translating that to Swift and got another error too. I updated the code snippet accordingly in my original post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Objective-C can only store objects in an `NSArray` which is why the float value had to be wrapped in a `NSNumber`. In Swift, this is much easier as you can just store the floats directly. Now that your `columns` array is of type `[CGFloat]` you can simply append the value without wrapping it as an `NSNumber`:

```
func addColumn(position: CGFloat) {
  self.columns.append(position)
}
```

You don't need to convert the values coming from the `columns` array because they're already floats:

```
for f in self.columns {
  CGContextMoveToPoint(ctx, f, 10)
  CGContextAddLineToPoint(ctx, f, self.bounds.size.height - 10)
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked perfectly. I'm slowly starting to see the good side of Swift.

Answer (score -3):

I believe this http://www.raywenderlich.com/87899/make-simple-drawing-app-uikit-swift aggregates more insights regarding this topics